# Drawing a border around a shape with swing

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way in java to draw a border around the last-drawn shape? e.g. if I have code that uses `graphics.fill`whatever to draw a shape, is there are method I can call after that without knowing what type of fill shape I drew that surrounds said shape with a border?

Comment: Sounds too specific to be a builtin function. How about you try implement it yourself?

Comment: Yep, make that part of the code in your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override, immediately after you have iterated through and drawn your shapes.

Comment: Ahh yeah that's pretty simple. I didn't think about just calling drawShape with radius, etc. being 1 more than the shape drawn.